# How do I save spark.writeStream results in hive?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-hive

I am using `spark.readStream` to read data from Kafka and running an explode on the resulting dataframe.
I am trying to save the result of the explode in a Hive table and I am not able to find any solution for that. 
I tried the following method but it doesn't work (it runs but I don't see any new partitions created)

```scala
val query = tradelines.writeStream.outputMode("append")
  .format("memory")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
  .queryName("tl")
  .start() 

sc.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;")

sc.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE default.tradelines PARTITION (dt) SELECT * FROM tl")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check HDFS for the `dt` partitions on the file system

You need to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` on the hive table to see new partitions.

If you aren't doing anything special with Spark, then it's worth pointing out that [Kafka Connect HDFS](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) is capable of registering Hive partitions directly from Kafka.